# Inconsistent results with CTE (Recursion)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I am pulling my hair with this one!

I have a Stored Procedure that runs everyday:

```
-- DECLARING DATE VARIABLES
    DECLARE @FirstDay date 
-- SETTING UP INITIAL VALUES TO DATE VARIABLES
    SET @FirstDay = (SELECT MIN(WK_Start) AS FirstDay FROM [TML_RDB].[COMPANY].[COMPANY_CALENDAR]);


    -- CREATE DATE RANGE FROM @FIRST DAY
    WITH DateRange AS (
    SELECT @FirstDay AS [Date]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD("dd",1,[Date]) FROM DateRange
    WHERE [Date] < DATEADD("dd",-1,DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE())+2,3,1)) 
    )

    SELECT CAST(CONCAT(YEAR(DR.[Date]),FORMAT(MONTH(DR.[Date]),'00'),FORMAT(DAY(DR.[Date]),'00')) AS int) AS [DateKey]
    ,DR.[Date]
    ,DATENAME(DW,DR.[Date]) AS [DayOfWeekName]  
    ,CONCAT(RIGHT(YEAR(DR.[Date]),2), FORMAT(DATEPART(WK, DATEADD("dd",-1,DR.[Date])),'00')) AS [CalendarWeek]
    ,CONCAT('W', RIGHT(YEAR(DR.[Date]),2), FORMAT(DATEPART(WK, DATEADD("dd",-1,DR.[Date])), '00')) AS [CalendarWeekName]
    ,(DATEPART(DW, DR.[Date])+5) % 7 + 1 AS [DayOfCalendarWeek]
    --,DATEPART(WK, DATEADD("dd",-1,DR.[Date])) AS [CalendarWeek]
    ,MONTH(DR.[Date]) AS [CalendarMonth]
    ,DATENAME(MM, DR.[Date]) AS [CalendarMonthName]
    ,DATEPART(DD,DR.[Date]) AS [DayOfCalendarMonth]
    ,DATEPART(QQ,DR.[Date]) AS [CalendarQuarter]
    ,CONCAT('Q', DATEPART(QQ,DR.[Date])) AS [CalendarQuarterName]
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(DR.[Date]), DATEPART(QQ,DR.[Date])  ORDER BY DR.[Date]) AS [DayOfCalendarQuarter]
    ,CASE 
        WHEN MONTH(DR.[Date]) < 7 THEN 1
        ELSE 2
    END AS [CalendarHalf]
    ,CASE 
        WHEN MONTH(DR.[Date]) < 7 THEN CONCAT('H',1)
        ELSE CONCAT('H',2)
    END AS [CalendarHalfName]
    ,CASE 
        WHEN YEAR(DR.[Date]) = 2009 
        THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(DR.[Date]), CASE WHEN MONTH(DR.[Date]) < 7 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END ORDER BY YEAR(DR.[Date]), CASE WHEN MONTH(DR.[Date]) < 7 THEN 1  ELSE 2 END) + DATEDIFF(DD,DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(DR.[Date]),1,1),DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(DR.[Date]),3,1)) 
        ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(DR.[Date]), CASE WHEN MONTH(DR.[Date]) < 7 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END ORDER BY YEAR(DR.[Date]), CASE WHEN MONTH(DR.[Date]) < 7 THEN 1  ELSE 2 END)
    END AS [DayOfCalendarHalf]
    ,YEAR(DR.[Date]) AS [CalendarYear]
    ,CONCAT('Y', YEAR(DR.[Date])) AS [CalendarYearName]
    ,CASE 
        WHEN YEAR(DR.[Date]) = 2009 
        THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(DR.[Date]) ORDER BY DR.[Date]) + DATEDIFF(DD,DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(DR.[Date]),1,1),DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(DR.[Date]),3,1)) 
        ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(DR.[Date]) ORDER BY DR.[Date])
    END AS [DayOfCalendarYear]  
    ,CC.[WK_Code] AS [FiscalWeek]
    ,'W' + CC.[WK_Code] AS [FiscalWeekName]
    ,DATEPART(DW,DR.[Date]) AS [DayOfFiscalWeek]
    ,CC.[Sun_Period] AS [FiscalPeriod]
    ,'P' + CC.[Sun_Period] AS [FiscalPeriodName]
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CC.[Sun_Period] ORDER BY CC.[Sun_Period]) AS [DayOfFiscalPeriod]
    ,CONCAT(LEFT(CC.[Sun_Period],2), FORMAT(CEILING(((CAST(Right(CC.[Sun_Period],2) AS int)) - 1)/3 ) + 1,'00')) AS [FiscalQuater]
    ,CONCAT('Q', LEFT(CC.[Sun_Period],2), FORMAT(CEILING(((CAST(Right(CC.[Sun_Period],2) AS int)) - 1)/3 ) + 1,'00')) AS [FiscalQuaterName]
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CONCAT(LEFT(CC.[Sun_Period],2), FORMAT(CEILING(((CAST(Right(CC.[Sun_Period],2) AS int)) - 1)/3 ) + 1,'00')) ORDER BY CONCAT(LEFT(CC.[Sun_Period],2), FORMAT(CEILING(((CAST(Right(CC.[Sun_Period],2) AS int)) - 1)/3 ) + 1,'00'))) AS [DayOfFiscalQuarter]
    ,CONCAT(LEFT(CC.[Sun_Period],2), FORMAT(CEILING(((CAST(Right(CC.[Sun_Period],2) AS int)) - 1)/6 ) + 1,'00')) AS [FiscalHalf]
    ,CONCAT('H', LEFT(CC.[Sun_Period],2), FORMAT(CEILING(((CAST(Right(CC.[Sun_Period],2) AS int)) - 1)/6 ) + 1,'00')) AS [FiscalHalfName]
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CONCAT(LEFT(CC.[Sun_Period],2), FORMAT(CEILING(((CAST(Right(CC.[Sun_Period],2) AS int)) - 1)/6 ) + 1,'00')) ORDER BY CONCAT(LEFT(CC.[Sun_Period],2), FORMAT(CEILING(((CAST(Right(CC.[Sun_Period],2) AS int)) - 1)/6 ) + 1,'00'))) AS [DayOfFiscalHalf]
    ,CONCAT(LEFT(YEAR(DR.[Date]),2), LEFT(CC.[Sun_Period],2)) AS [FiscalYear]
    ,CONCAT('Y', LEFT(YEAR(DR.[Date]),2), LEFT(CC.[Sun_Period],2)) AS [FiscalYearName]
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CONCAT(LEFT(YEAR(DR.[Date]),2), LEFT(CC.[Sun_Period],2)) ORDER BY CONCAT(LEFT(YEAR(DR.[Date]),2), LEFT(CC.[Sun_Period],2))) AS [DayOfFiscalYear]
    FROM DateRange DR
    INNER JOIN [TML_RDB].[COMPANY].[COMPANY_CALENDAR] CC
    ON DR.[Date] >= CC.[WK_Start] AND DR.[Date] <= CC.[WK_End]
    OPTION (MAXRECURSION 10000)
```

When the above query is run using the Stored Procedure, i get the an output which is incorrect:

[image]

This count should start again from 1, not 217.

Now, what is weird is when i run this query manually i get the below result which is correct:

[image]

Some important infomration:

- This query on some occasions returns the correct results, other times it does not.
- The correct result is returned why i reduce the number of rows (Years)

This is to do with the Recursion but cannot undertand it fully.
Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Please try to include a miminal example of the case. It's difficult for us to debug a big query. It may easily fall into the TL;DR; category.

Comment: Since your order by expression is the same as your partition by expression, the result is not deterministic. This means every execution a row can get a different number. You'll probably get more reliable results if you make your order by deterministic (means order by a unique expression).